# I have an array of objects and i want to show the div on mouseenter

Tags: jquery, arrays, hover

I have an array of objects and i want to show the div: title-list on mouseenter. And afterwards hide when the mouse leave.  The problem is that i can't make it work on every each objekt.  I can only make it work one single objekt, or all of them at the same time:

Here is the code:

```
    <body>

     <div class="row" style="margin-right: 0px;">

        <div class="container">
            <?php

                $q = "SELECT * FROM votes ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

                while($vote_list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { ?>

                <div class="col-md-6 vote-list" id="test" style="background-image: url(<?php echo
                 $vote_list['url']; ?>)">         
                    <a href="view.php?id=<?php echo $vote_list['id']; ?>">
                        <div class="title-list" id="titleview">
                            <p class="texttitle"><?php echo $vote_list['text']; ´?></p>
                        </div> 
                    </a>
                </div>


            <?php } ?>
        </div>
</div> 

 </body>    

 <script>
 var cancel = false;
 $("div.vote-list").hover(function(){
 $("#titleview").show();
 },function(){
 if(!cancel)
  $("#titleview").hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to reference the current `.vote-list`.

```
var cancel = false;
$("div.vote-list").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".title-list").show();
}, function () {
    if (!cancel) $(this).find(".title-list").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @pmandell has correctly pointed out, you would have to use the context of the hovered element to determine which to toggle. **It also appears that you're duplicating IDs .. all your div.vote-list have the same id: test. That leads to HTML that's not valid.**

I would also want to point out that it is more advisable to use `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`:

```
    var cancel = false;
    $("div.vote-list").on('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).find(".title-list").show();
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function () {
        cancel || $(this).find(".title-list").hide();
    });
```

```js
    var cancel = false;
    $("div.vote-list").on('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).find(".title-list").show();
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function () {
        cancel || $(this).find(".title-list").hide();
    });
```

```css
.titleview {
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <div class="col-md-6 vote-list" style="">1         
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="title-list titleview">
                            <p class="texttitle">Some text</p>
                        </div> 
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 vote-list" style="">2         
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="title-list titleview">
                            <p class="texttitle">Some text</p>
                        </div> 
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 vote-list" style="">3         
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="title-list titleview">
                            <p class="texttitle">Some text</p>
                        </div> 
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 vote-list" style="">4         
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="title-list titleview">
                            <p class="texttitle">Some text</p>
                        </div> 
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 vote-list" style="">5         
                    <a href="">
                        <div class="title-list titleview">
                            <p class="texttitle">Some text</p>
                        </div> 
                    </a>
                </div>
```